# How would i capture the desktop and stream it to a browserview?

Tags: html, css, electron

How would i capture the desktop and stream it to a browserview?

I have this preload script, but it doesn't do anything:

```
const { desktopCapturer } = require("electron");
/* Screen capture */
window.navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia = () => {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      const sources = await desktopCapturer.getSources({ types: ['screen', 'window'] })
      const selectionElem = document.createElement('div')
      selectionElem.classList = 'desktop-capturer-selection'
      selectionElem.innerHTML = `
      <style>
.desktop-capturer-selection {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100vh;
background: rgba(30,30,30,.75);
color: #fff;
z-index: 10000000;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
}
.desktop-capturer-selection__scroller {
width: 100%;
max-height: 100vh;
overflow-y: auto;
}
.desktop-capturer-selection__list {
max-width: calc(100% - 100px);
margin: 50px;
padding: 0;
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
list-style: none;
overflow: hidden;
justify-content: center;
}
.desktop-capturer-selection__item {
display: flex;
margin: 4px;
}
.desktop-capturer-selection__btn {
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
align-items: stretch;
width: 145px;
margin: 0;
border: 0;
border-radius: 3px;
padding: 4px;
background: #252626;
text-align: left;
transition: background-color .15s, box-shadow .15s;
}
.desktop-capturer-selection__btn:hover,
.desktop-capturer-selection__btn:focus {
background: rgba(98,100,167,.8);
}
.desktop-capturer-selection__thumbnail {
width: 100%;
height: 81px;
object-fit: cover;
}
.desktop-capturer-selection__name {
margin: 6px 0 6px;
white-space: nowrap;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
overflow: hidden;
}
</style>
        <div class="desktop-capturer-selection__scroller">
          <ul class="desktop-capturer-selection__list">
            ${sources.map(({id, name, thumbnail, display_id, appIcon}) => `
              <li class="desktop-capturer-selection__item">
                <button class="desktop-capturer-selection__btn" data-id="${id}" title="${name}">
                  <img class="desktop-capturer-selection__thumbnail" src="${thumbnail.toDataURL()}" />
                  <span class="desktop-capturer-selection__name">${name}</span>
                </button>
              </li>
            `).join('')}
          </ul>
        </div>
      `
      document.body.appendChild(selectionElem)
      document.querySelectorAll('.desktop-capturer-selection__btn')
        .forEach(button => {
          button.addEventListener('click', async () => {
            try {
              const id = button.getAttribute('data-id')
              const source = sources.find(source => source.id === id)
              if(!source) {
                throw new Error(`Source with id ${id} does not exist`)
              }
              const stream = await window.navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
                audio: false,
                video: {
                  mandatory: {
                    chromeMediaSource: 'desktop'//,
                    //chromeMediaSourceId: source.id
                  }
                }
              })
              resolve(stream)
              selectionElem.remove()
            } catch (err) {
              console.error('Error selecting desktop capture source:', err)
              reject(err)
            }
          })
        })
    } catch (err) {
      console.error('Error displaying desktop capture sources:', err)
      reject(err)
    }
  })
}
```

Am i using it incorectly, or am i missing something?

Also, the site i am loading it into is https://meet.google.com

If needed, i can upload my files.

also, this is on github: https://github.com/oxmc/google-meet-desktop.

Comment: You don't have to use a script for streaming desktop to google meet, do u? There is already an inbuilt option for that

Comment: It doesn't detect the screen.

Comment: Probably a bug. Did u try reinstalling it?

Comment: Reinstall electron? Yes, i have, but it still doesn't detect the screen.